# Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WP_Term as array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, taxonomy-terms

I had this issue since I updated my WordPress, in my website I have a custom post which contains some custom categories, something like that:

1) **Parent category**: Food |
   **Child**: Fries, Hamburger, Maple Syrup…

2) **Parent category**: Year |
   **Child**: 2016, 2015, 2014…

3) **Parent category**: Country |
   **Child**: USA, Canada, Spain…

So when I'm writting my custom post, I would chose within those categories and just choose (tickle the box) the category that I need. And it would shown something like that:

**Title**: New recipe

**Content**: My text

**Terms**: *Food: Mapple Syrup* / *Country: Canada* / *Year: 2014*

But now, the terms doesn't show at all, and I get this error message:
 **Cannot use object of type WP_Term as array**

I used to have the following PHP code which allowed to me to retrieve the child category's parent (and used it as a prefix) and also allowed to me change the order.

```
  $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'project_cat', array("fields" => "all"));
                            $terms_hierarchy = array();
                            foreach ($term_list as $term_single) {
                                $parent = $term_single->parent;
                                if ($parent != 0) {
                                    $terms_hierarchy[$parent][] = get_term($parent)->slug;
                                    $terms_hierarchy[$parent]['children'][$term_single->term_id] = $term_single->name;
                                } else {
                                    $terms_hierarchy[$parent] = $term_single;
                                }
                            }
   //PHP indicated this line:
                            foreach ($terms_hierarchy as $key => $term) {
                                echo "<span>$term[0]: </span>";
                                if (!empty($term['children'])) {
                                    $s_children = '';
                                    foreach ($term['children'] as $key => $child) {
                                        if ($term[0] == 'client') {
                                            $tax_meta = get_term_meta($key);
                                            if(!empty($tax_meta['external_url'][0])){
                                               $s_children .= "<a target='_blank' href='{$tax_meta['external_url'][0]}'>$child</a>, ";
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                $s_children .= $child . ', ';
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            $s_children .= $child . ', ';
                                        }
                                    }
                                    echo rtrim($s_children, ', ') . "<br />";
                                }
                            }
```

I'll be really grateful if someone can help to figure out what went wrong?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but so far I couldn't fix the problem on my own… At the moment, my temporarily solution is to remove the line but then, most of my categories would disappear… Would highly appreciate some tips!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

$terms_hierarchy is not an array it is an Std Object. So ...

$term['children']

... would actually be ...

$term->children

Comment: Thank you for helping me out!